# CCLocationManager says I'm in London

Tags: ios, geolocation, cllocationmanager

I've got this problem since a few days... Cant figure out why but this method :

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

    long now = [[[NSDate alloc] init] timeIntervalSince1970];

    //avoid cached locations
    if(abs([newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow]) > 15.0f)
    {
        return;
    }
    //avoid more the 1KM location
    if(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 1000 || newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    //if we already located, no need to go any further
    if(alreadyLocated)
    {
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        return;
    }
    alreadyLocated = YES;
    [self stopLocating];
    [[SPPreferenceHandler getInstance] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithLong:now] forKey:LAST_LOCATION_UPDATE];
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        //blabla some code
    }
}
```

Always says I'm in London :

> Printing description of currentLocation: <+51.50998000,-0.13370000>...

I have no clue what is going on...
For info, I'm testing on an iPhone 5, tested it plugged to the Mac and unplugged... Same problem persists.

If you guys could help me out ! That'd be great !

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so here it is just in case some people are stuck like me with this kind of error :

Make sure to go to Product -> Scheme -> Edit, then UNCHECK "allow location simulation"